# C program crashes just after giving last input

Tags: c

This program takes input from user product name, product class and product family and then stores it into a file. But after giving inputs and pressing enter program crashes saying product.exe has stopped working.

Here's the code-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void add_new_product(void);
struct product
{
    char P_name;
    char P_class;
    char P_family;
}P[100];
FILE *fp;
void add_new_product()
{
    char ch;
    int i=0;
    fp=fopen("product.txt","w+");
       do
        {
            clrscr();
            printf("\t\t\t Add New Product");
            printf("\n User:");
            printf("\n\n\n \t\t\t 1.Product Name   :");
            printf("\n\n \t\t\t 2.Product Class  :");
            printf("\n\n \t\t\t 3.Product Family :");
            gotoxy(44,5);
            scanf("%s",&P[i].P_name);
            gotoxy(44,7);
            scanf("%s",&P[i].P_class);
            gotoxy(44,9);
            scanf("%s",&P[i].P_family);
            fprintf(fp,"%s %s %s %s %s %s",P[i].P_family,"|",P[i].P_class,"|",P [i].P_name,";");
        printf("\n \t\t Do you  want to add another product?(Y/N) :");
        scanf("%s",&ch);
        i++;
      }while((ch=='Y')||(ch=='y'));
        fclose(fp);
}

int main()
{
    add_new_product();
    getch();
    return 0;
}

}
```

Comment: u are trying to read string in character variable:scanf("%s",&P[i].P_name);

Comment: yes I know but program takes input fine .

Comment: First please upgrade your compiler to modern standards.  That `gotoxy` is probably from Turbo C++, a compiler that is 25 years old.  Then once you do that, use `std::string`.

Comment: "yes I know but program takes input fine" sounds stupid. It takes input fine because there are 100 elements, all being overwritten...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you are reading **string** from `scanf` you need to modify your `structure` as below:

```
#define MAX_LENGTH 100

struct product
{
    char P_name[MAX_LENGTH];
    char P_class[MAX_LENGTH];
    char P_family[MAX_LENGTH];
}P[100];
```

Comment: How can you store the value in pointer variable without allocating them?

Comment: And then they will have undefined behavior due to writing to a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The correct code should be:

```
struct product
{
    char P_name[255];
    char P_class[255];
    char P_family[255];
}P[100];
```